# CiviEvent and Contribution pages always redirect back to homepage

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, registration

I am helping someone update a website that is using CiviCRM and our goal is to make it so the Event registrations and contributions (that we are using for membership signup). The main issue we are having right now is that any of the Live Page Links for either of this always redirect back to the homepage with no error message.

We are able to see those pages as Administrator users, but for un-logged in users, it always redirects. We tried having WordPress Subscriber users able to do the registrations as well, but the same redirection kept happening.

As soon as I change that user from Subscriber to Administrator it starts working again.

I am not overly familiar with CiviCRM yet, but I cannot find any details about this kind of problem - what am I overlooking?